# i'm trying to create a calendar in my iOS app with Swift but i can't grab day, weekday, or year values from Date()

Tags: arrays, swift, date, time, calendar

the date comes up with the proper current time, YYYY-MM-DD-etc.
The month is the only thing that comes up properly with "12" since it's December. the other values show 0.

This is my swift variable file:

```
import Foundation
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
let weekday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)**
```

I feel like I've tried everything here. any suggestions on how I can get the proper values for my calendar or does anyone know a preset calendar with code i can just copy into my app?

Comment: I'm getting reponse when I print(day, weekday, month, year) as op -> (27, 2 ,12, 2021) what is the issue you facing. do you want everything in this format ?

Comment: can you please make sure what issue you facing with code or in what format you want the date ?

Comment: Works okay for me

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd"
let day = formatter.string(from: date)
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
let weekday = formatter.string(from: date)
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
let month = formatter.string(from: date)
formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY"
let year = formatter.string(from: date)
```

[image]

Hope I was helpful.